Wait for callback to finish
suppose I have this React/Javascript code:
const doVerifyThingy = (thingyId: string): boolean => {
  dispatch(verifyThingyInBE(thingyId))
    .then((response) => {
      return response.payload as boolean;
    })
    .catch();
  return false;
};

const handleButtonClick = () => {
  const ok = doVerifyThingy("254dghfgt6346");
  if (ok)
    go_to_next_step();
  else
    alert("things are not ok!");
}

When I click a button, handleButtonClick() asks BE if things are alright, and if so we can continue.
The problem is that doVerifyThingy() returns immediately, without waiting for the ".then" event.
So how can I make doVerifyThingy() "thenable" ?
verifyThingyInBE() is by the way async with await calls.

You should return promise from doVerifyThingy so that we can await for return value for ok as:
// return type Promise<boolean>
const doVerifyThingy = (thingyId: string): Promise<boolean> => {

    // Added return 
    return dispatch(verifyThingyInBE(thingyId))
    .then((response) => {
      return response.payload as boolean;
    })
    .catch(err => {
        // DO SOMETHING WITH ERROR
        // returning false if something goes wrong
        return false;
    });
  
};

// You can either use `async-await` or use doVerifyThingy("254dghfgt6346").then()
// I've added async so that we can await for it
const handleButtonClick = async () => {

  // awaiting till Promise resolve
  const ok = await doVerifyThingy("254dghfgt6346");
  if (ok)
    go_to_next_step();
  else
    alert("things are not ok!");
}

